# Is inserting an element into an array of known size constant time?

Tags: python, arrays, insert

I have an `input array of integers` that I am iterating through.

For each iteration, I am doing some computation, and there is a chance that I will add the number I am iterating over to another array that I will maintain of size 3.

For example:

```
input array = [1,5,10,4,2,10,4]
res = [2,4,5]

for i in range(len(array)): 
    .... 
    res.append(array[i])
    res = res[:3]
```

As you can see, at the end of each insertion into res, I am slicing the array, to maintain just three elements in it.

Am I right in understanding that the **Time Complexity of the insertion** is **constant time?** Since for each insertion I will move at most three elements to the right (even though I know in python arrays are dynamic, and this is done in the background).

And just to confirm the **algorithm's time complexity is thus O(n)**? If my above assumption is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which is optimized for that, and will keep the size constant for you:

> Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from
> either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance
> in either direction.

If `maxlen` is specified,

> the deque is bounded to the specified maximum length. Once a bounded
> length deque is full, when new items are added, a corresponding number
> of items are discarded from the opposite end.

So, your code simply becomes

```
from collections import deque

input array = [1,5,10,4,2,10,4]
res = deque([2,4,5], maxlen=3)

for i in range(len(array)): 
    .... 
    res.append(array[i])
```

and the size of `res` remains constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thierry, can I just confirm that all my assumptions above are correct then? And deque from collections is simply to optimise things even further?